# Cakephp: Print a comment after queries in Sql log

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, mysql

I'm using CakePHP 2.3 with the debug kit plugin and I need print a commentary after each Sql query in my logs. Is it possible modify it?

Comment: Why would you need that? Those are (tmp) log files - not a diary :) can you please elaborate?

Comment: I would have to do this to explain what happens in the database and add other queries that have not been done as an example.

Comment: The queries in that log represent **all** queries done in that specific request. What do you mean by adding other queries? You can only add queries by simply _executing_ them, via CakePHP's model methods.

Comment: It is for external reader logs. The goal is to add commands, variables ... before and after the queries. I have a solution, if it works I write here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, I created an instance of `Mysql` in `Model/Datasource` called `DboCustomSource`. Here I have overwritten the function `execute` of `DboSource` to modify the variable `$sql`.

```
App::uses('Mysql', 'Model/Datasource/Database');

class DboCustomSource extends Mysql{ 

    public function execute($sql, $options = array(), $params = array()){
        $sql .= 'comment';           
        return parent::execute($sql, $options, $params);
    }
}
```

It's necessary to modify `datasource` in database's configuration: `'datasource' => 'DboCustomSource'`.